# Find all positive integers satisfying $n \mid 5^n+1 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**Find all positive integer satisfying $5^n+1 \vdots n$**

Here is my attempt:
Introducing $p$ as the smallest prime divisor of $n$.
Let $ord_p(5)=h \in \mathbb{N^*}$
Therefore $h \mid 2n; h \mid p-1$ on account of FLT.
Then $h \mid \text{GCD} (p-1;2n)$. Since $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$, $\text{GCD} (p-1;n)=1$. Hence, $h \mid 2 \implies h \in \{ 1;2\} \implies p \in \{ 2;3 \}$.

- $p=2$. Let $n=2^k.t; k;t$ are positive integer and $t$ is odd.
  We have $2^k \mid 5^{2^k.t}+1=(5^{2^k}+1)[5^{2^k(t-1)}-5^{2^k(t-2)}+...+1] $. Noting that $t$ is odd, the formula in the bracket is odd. Therefore $2^k \mid 5^{2^k}+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \implies k=1$. Therefore $t \mid 5^{2t}+1$.

It is noticeable that $t=1;n=2$ satisfies the conditions.

When $t \ge 3$ then there exist the smallest prime divisor $q$ of $t$. Let $ord_q(5)=g$. We have $g \mid q-1; g\mid 4t$; this implies $g \mid 4$ since $\text{GCD} (q-1;t)=1$. Hence, $q \in \{ 3;13 \}$. Since $5^{2t}+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, we have $q=13 \implies t=13^s.u;u;s \in \mathbb{N^*}; (u;(2;3;5;7;11;13))=1$.

+, It is easy to see that $n=2.13^s; \forall s$ satisfies the conditions as according to LTE lemma, we have $v_{13}(5^n+1)=v_{13}(25^t+1)=v_{13}(25+1)+v_{13}(t)=s+1 > s=v_{13}(13^s); 5^n+1 \vdots 2$.
+, However, I can't solve for $u > 1$, $p=3$.

** Despite what I've illustrated, I found out that if $5^w+1 \vdots r$; for some $r$ prime then $n \vdots r$.
I'm looking forward to the solution to this problems :)

Comment: this is [A015951](https://oeis.org/A015951).  Not sure there is a useful characterization of the list...

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cmid%205%5En%2B1%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [n | 5^{n}+1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1841677p12378375).

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved that for any number $a \in \mathbb N$ such that $a\neq 2^k; k\in \mathbb N$ there are infinitely many number like $n\in\mathbb N$such that $n|a^n+1$.For proving this theorem following Lemma is used:

Lemma: If for integer $k\geq0$, $a^{p^k}+1$ is divisible by $p^{k+1}$
(a is natural number and p is odd prime), then:

$p^{k+2}|a^{p^{k+1}}$

For when  n is  odd and $a=5$ we may write:

$(6-1)^n+1=6k\Rightarrow 6|5^n+1 $

Also :

$5^p\equiv 5\bmod p$

$5^3+1\equiv 6\equiv 0\bmod 3\bmod \Rightarrow 3|5^3+1$

Let $p=3$, Using the lemma we have:

$3^{k+2}|5^{3^{k+1}+1}$

For $k=0$:

$ 3^{0+2}|5^{3^{0+1}}+1\Rightarrow 3^2|5^3+1 $

So we have infinite numbers like $n=3^k$; $k\in \mathbb N$ which suffices the condition.

$9|5^9+1$, $27|5^{27}+1$, $81|5^{81}+1$. . . .

Comment: Yes, i think your lemma is exquisitely depicted but I want some kind of generalisation to the n-s that satisfy the conditions.